# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

How do I substitute `http://mydomain.com/dir1/dir2/test.php` for `http://mydomain.com/test.php`?

Comment: It would help to mention platform/webserver. I'm guessing at a flavour of Apache with the mod_rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to mention platform/webserver. I'm guessing at a flavour of Apache with the mod_rewrite module.

If everything is under this new subdir, redirect root ie.

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule   ^/$  /dir1/dir2/  [R]`

or if you want ot explicit about a single file.

`RewriteEngine  on`

`RewriteRule    ^/test.php  /dir1/dir2/test.php  [R]`

M.